# Getting static function call graph of a COBOL program in java

Tags: java, parsing, call-graph

I have to parse COBOL code in the aim of producing an easy and understandable overview of the program. I would like to use Java for its effienciency/security compromise.
I am not aware of all the tools around, but I know having the right tool for this task will make things a lot easier!

So I need a tool to produce the function call graph, to me that means basically writing a parser...
I think JavaCC is a good choice, there is also ANTLR... Can these tools creates the function call graph structure?

What's a good way to work with lexical analyzers in the aim of plotting the function call graph? I mean that I don't want to rewrite code that is already implemented in these tools but I am not aware of.

Thank you

Comment: You will find that writing a parser for a real programming langauge is lots harder than it looks because of all the cruft that the language/dialect designers have added over the years.  Then you will discover you need to semantically analyze the code to get whatever you want (in this case, function call information) [and you'll discover indirect function calls].  YOu dont want to do this from scratch.   Find a tool that does most of it, or you'll never get the part that you want done.

Comment: **FAR** too broad. Writing a Cobol parser is seriously no joke, even with  the assistance of a parser generator.

Comment: Maybe I can reducing the task to only searching for function calls, without parsing the all code (it's valid code, so I don't need to check it). But still, I think at the end I need to parse it to make the difference between functions and other instructions... But I can simplify the gramar a lot with functions/everything else.
So parsing COBOL may be hard, but for my needs I won't write a full COBOL parser but some parser for COBOL inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of ProLeap COBOL parser.

You could use the Java-based [ProLeap COBOL parser](https://github.com/uwol/proleap-cobol-parser) to extract calls to [paragraphs](https://github.com/uwol/proleap-cobol-parser/blob/477781281be2f094d94b704ce28669c5d053133e/src/test/java/io/proleap/cobol/asg/call/ParagraphCallTest.java#L32), [sections](https://github.com/uwol/proleap-cobol-parser/blob/477781281be2f094d94b704ce28669c5d053133e/src/test/java/io/proleap/cobol/asg/call/SectionCallTest.java#L32), [data description entries](https://github.com/uwol/proleap-cobol-parser/blob/477781281be2f094d94b704ce28669c5d053133e/src/test/java/io/proleap/cobol/asg/call/DataDescriptionEntryCallTest.java#L36) etc. The parser will provide you with the call graph, however graphical plotting would have to be added.

So, for example this paragraph call ...

```
 IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
 PROGRAM-ID. SECTIONCLL.
 DATA DIVISION.
 PROCEDURE DIVISION.
 INIT.
    PERFORM INIT.
```

... could be analysed with the following Java code, returning 1 call in this example:

```
package io.proleap.cobol.asg.call;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import java.io.File;

import org.junit.Test;

import io.proleap.cobol.CobolTestBase;
import io.proleap.cobol.asg.metamodel.CompilationUnit;
import io.proleap.cobol.asg.metamodel.Program;
import io.proleap.cobol.asg.metamodel.ProgramUnit;
import io.proleap.cobol.asg.metamodel.procedure.Paragraph;
import io.proleap.cobol.asg.metamodel.procedure.ProcedureDivision;
import io.proleap.cobol.asg.runner.impl.CobolParserRunnerImpl;
import io.proleap.cobol.preprocessor.CobolPreprocessor.CobolSourceFormatEnum;

public class ParagraphCallTest extends CobolTestBase {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        final File inputFile = new File("src/test/resources/io/proleap/cobol/asg/call/ParagraphCall.cbl");
        final Program program = new CobolParserRunnerImpl().analyzeFile(inputFile, CobolSourceFormatEnum.TANDEM);

        final CompilationUnit compilationUnit = program.getCompilationUnit("ParagraphCall");
        final ProgramUnit programUnit = compilationUnit.getProgramUnit();
        final ProcedureDivision procedureDivision = programUnit.getProcedureDivision();

        final Paragraph paragraph = procedureDivision.getParagraph("Init");
        assertNotNull(paragraph);
        assertEquals(1, paragraph.getCalls().size());
    }
}
```

The ProLeap COBOL parser is licensed under an open source license, so it can be used for free.

Comment: Quite nice! I was thinking of using ANTLR also because it already has a COBOL grammar file written.
I may inspire my program on yours, thank you!

Comment: Actually, the ProLeap COBOL parser is based on ANTLR and the COBOL grammar file mentioned by you. The ANTLR COBOL grammar has been written by me for purpose of this parser.